# In an enum class, how can one cast values as dates?

Tags: java, enums

In an enum class, how can one cast a value as the type `java.util.date`?
The enum still has to have a name.

I have tried:

```
ENUM_OPTION1(Date(10000000000L))
```

But I got an error saying that
"Symbol Date(long) wasn't recognized", even though I imported the class at the top of my file.

Comment: Java developers usually use `new` to create instances, not just the class name ...

Comment: FYI, `java.util.Date` is a terrible class that was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically `Instant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `new Date( … )`

Use `new` to instantiate a `java.util.Date`.

```
ENUM_OPTION1( new Date( 10_000_000_000L ) )
```

FYI, `java.util.Date` is a terrible class that was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

## Full example

Add a constructor on your enum. On each instance of the enum you declare, call the constructor. To that constructor, pass the specific date. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum History {
    US_DECLARATION_OF_INDEPENDENCE( LocalDate.of( 1776 , Month.July , 4 ) ) ,
    US_CONSTITIUTION_APPROVED( LocalDate.of( 1787 , 9 , 17 ) ) 
    ;

    private LocalDate localDate ;

    // Constructor
    public History( LocalDate ld ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( ld ) ;
        this.localDate = ld ;
    }

    // Getter
    public LocalDate getLocalDate() {
        return this.localDate ;
    }

}
```

To use this enum, call the instance method on one of the named constant instances.

```
LocalDate ld = History.US_DECLARATION_OF_INDEPENDENCE.getLocalDate() ;
```